# Trouble extracting photos from CD wrote in Egypt

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc, pictures

I recently visited Egypt and had some photos taken of an underwater dive. The chap wrote a CD with the photos on. I have put it into my computer and there appears to be nothing on the CD.

However when I inserted the CD into my brother in laws Mac book pro whilst we were on holiday the pictures were there. Is there a way I can access the pictures on my computer? My brother in law lives really quite far away and he is the only person I know with a MAC

I have a ACER Travel mate P253 laptop running Windows 7 professional SP1.

Comment: What Region is your CD/DVD Player Made for?  See [DVD Region Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code)

Comment: CDs dont have region codes.  DVDs do, but thats just for DVD-Video.

Comment: Does you drive read other CDs OK?  I'd bet your brother isn't the only person you know with a computer -- why not try that CD in a computer of someone that's close(r) to you?

Comment: yah my computer reads cds fine it also will not read on my gfs windows 8 machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful or reasons you cant read the CD, but there isnt much point in going into it.

To solve your issue, I would just have your brother copy the images and burn a new CD.  Or he can put them into a DropBox, or similar cloud storage site, so you can download them.

Comment: It's a question/answer website; I'd say there is a lot of point in going into the possible reasons...

Comment: his question was *how* he can access them, not why.  IMO, he isnt interested in the technical aspects, but the end result.